# My contact search isn't working with a Letter to match the phonenook on iPhone 6S Plus

Tags: iphone

My contact search isn't working. When I write a letter on the search bar, it doesn't find the match on the phone book although I have these contacts saved on my phone. I now have to manually go over a list of 500 to find a contact. I have iPhone 6S Plus and never had that issue before. 
I have tried group contacts, hide all, then show all and it still doesn't work.
Please any help or advise?

Comment: Did you restart your phone and tried again?

Comment: Yes I did and it's still not working